# Reading a file of arbitrary length in C

Tags: c, file, fread

What's the most idiomatic/efficient way to read a file of arbitrary length in C?

1. Get the filesize of the file in bytes and issue a single `fread()`
2. Keep `fread()`ing a constant size buffer until getting EOF
3. Anything else?

Comment: It depends from what you need to do with such data...

Comment: memory mapping usually quite good

Comment: just mmap(2) it.

Comment: @n.m. what makes you think OP's platform supports `mmap` syscall? :)

Comment: @n.m. Some unfortunate users have to use Windows, which is not POSIX compliant. I am happy to never having used Windows in my life, but this is a privilege.

Comment: The problem with #1 (get the filesize in bytes and issue a single `freed()`) is what happens if the file is much larger than you expect?  You could end up taxing or exhausting your virtual memory.  With a decent-size buffer, #2 should do just fine.

Comment: If your OS doesn't have `mmap(2)`, it probably has `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`. Or maybe not, who knows. Not every file can be memory mapped (but if you can tell its size, you probably can map it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using any technique which requires knowing the size of the file in advance. That leaves exactly one technique: read the file a bit at a time, in blocks of a convenient size.

Here's why you don't want to try to find the filesize in advance:

1. If it is not a regular file, there may not be any way to tell. For example, you might be reading directly from a console, or taking piped input from a previous data generator. If your program requires the filesize to be knowable, these useful input mechanisms will not be available to your users, who will complain or choose a different tool.
2. Even if you can figure out the filesize, you have no way of preventing it from changing while you are reading the file. If you are not careful about how you read the file, you might open a vulnerability which could be exploited by adversarial programs.

   For example, if you allocate a buffer of the "correct" size and then read until you get an end-of-file condition, you may end up overwriting random memory. (Multiple reads may be necessary if you use an interface like `read()` which might read less data than requested.) Or you might find that the file has been truncated; if you don't check the amount of data read, you might end up processing uninitialised memory leading to information leakage.

Comment: I think point 2 needs to be elaborated. If done correctly, changing file size after it's being gathered but before file is read with a single `fread` call will not by itself make program vulnerable.

Comment: @sergeya: if you use a single fread you won't do a buffer overriun if the file increases in size but you might not notice that the end of your input buffer is full of garbage if the file is truncated. That's harder but not impossible to exploit, depending on what else is going on.

Comment: That's what I meant. Increasing file size will not affect program in any way, and decreasing it's size will lead to fread returning less bytes than requested. So I really don't see any vulnerability here (unless program doesn't check return value of fread call, but than all bets are off anyways).

Comment: @SergeyA: I agree that the first reason is more important, which is why I put it first. Anyway, most vulnerabilities really come from things like not checking return values rather than unsafe interfaces *per se*; most of the code I've seen which does a single `fread` does not, in fact, check the return value because the coder had convinced themselves that they knew how much data would be read. If you did it correctly and checked everything, then you'd be safe but the code would be just about as wordy as the better option of reading the file in chunks.

Comment: Agreed. I do not think we have an argument here, we are pretty much in agreement. On a side note, anyone who doesn't check return values of system or library calls which are to return a value should clearly educate themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, you usually don't need to keep the entire file content in memory. You'll often [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the file (notably if it is textual), or at least read the file in smaller pieces, and for that you don't need it entirely in memory. For a textual file, reading it line-by-line (perhaps with some state inside your parser) is often enough (using [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) or [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)).

[Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) exist (notably on [disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) or [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive)s) because usually they can be much "bigger" than your computer RAM. Actually, files have been invented (more than 50 years ago) to be able to deal with data larger than memory. [Distributed file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system#Distributed_file_systems) also can be very big (and accessed remotely even from a laptop, e.g. by [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), [CIFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block), etc...)

Some [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) are capable of storing petabytes of data (on supercomputers), with individual files of many terabytes (much larger than available RAM).

You'll also likely to use some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)s. These routinely have terabytes of data. See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/332071/40065) answer (about realistic size of [`sqlite`](https://sqlite.org/) databases).

If you really want to read a file entirely in memory using stdio (but you should avoid doing that, because you generally want your program to be able to handle a lot of data on files; so reading the entire file in memory is generally a design error), you indeed could loop on [fread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) (or [fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), or even [fgetc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc)) till end-of-file. Notice that [feof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) is useful only *after* some input operation.

On current laptop or desktop computers, you could prefer (for efficiency) to use buffers of a few megabytes, and you certainly can deal with big files of several hundreds of gigabytes (much larger than your RAM).

On POSIX file systems, you might do [memory mapped IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) with e.g. [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) - but that might not be faster than [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) with large buffers (of a few megabytes). You could use [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) (Linux specific) and [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) (or [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) if using `mmap`) to tune performance by hinting your OS [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)).

If you have to code for Microsoft Windows, you could study its [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list) and [find](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20mmap) some way to do memory mapped IO.

In practice, file data (notably if it was accessed recently) often stays in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), which is of paramount importance for performance. When that is not the case, your hardware (disk, controller, ...) becomes the bottleneck and your program becomes [I/O bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) (in that case, no software trick could improve significantly the performance).

Comment: `mmap` by itself will not be faster than `fread`. The only way to make `mmap` faster than `fread` is by having two threads - one doing actual parsing, and another one fetching data.

Comment: On Linux, `fopen` with the `m` flag is doing `mmap`